How to solve Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: superState must be null on Xamarin Forms Android?
An app I've developed using Xamarin Forms, and published to Google Play Store (ad-hoc), is reporting a crash affecting users with the error: Java.lang.IllegalStateException: superState must be null. The app makes calls to an API for the services it provides to the user, such as logging in to their account, request PDF certifications, view their information and payments, etc.
The stack trace provided by Android Vitals:
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: superState must be null
  at androidx.customview.view.AbsSavedState$2.createFromParcel (AbsSavedState.java:95)
  at androidx.customview.view.AbsSavedState$2.createFromParcel (AbsSavedState.java:90)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal (Parcel.java:4880)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4633)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4402)
  at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal (Parcel.java:5493)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4717)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:4402)
  at android.os.Parcel.-$$Nest$mreadValue
  at android.os.Parcel$LazyValue.apply (Parcel.java:4500)
  at android.os.Parcel$LazyValue.apply (Parcel.java:4459)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.unwrapLazyValueFromMapLocked (BaseBundle.java:415)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValueAt (BaseBundle.java:401)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue (BaseBundle.java:381)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue (BaseBundle.java:364)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue (BaseBundle.java:357)
  at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray (Bundle.java:1108)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState (PhoneWindow.java:2282)
  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState (Activity.java:1913)
  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState (Activity.java:1866)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState (Instrumentation.java:1503)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:4222)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:225)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:205)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:177)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:98)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2693)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:230)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:319)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:9063)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:588)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)

Can provide MainActivity.cs code if requested.
Using Xamarin 17.11.0.98; Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.5.
I haven't been able to reproduce this exception at will using an emulator nor my physical Android phone. Also, I'm unable to discern where the error happens pertaining to my Xamarin Forms code (C#). It is my understanding that the stack trace points to a block of code generated deep in the underbelly of the Android layer that Xamarin Forms compiles and runs.
Things I've tried:
Following this, possibly related, blog post from James Montemagno, I implemented the subtle delays before async calls to the API as an attempt to fix the exception. I also optimized some async calls (merging some related ones to a single call to the API) as a means to lower the network and performance impact on both the app and API. I published a version with these delays and optimizations implemented, but the day after, Android Vitals reported the same exception happened to a user using said latest version. So, I think we can rule that solution out.
I also found this github issue with an almost identical stack trace as mine. It seems they solved it by adding a "@JvmField" annotation to the "CREATOR" object in what I presume to be a Kotlin(.kt) file (referenced commit). However, as I said before, I'm using Xamarin Forms and, as far as I know, I don't have access to edit that sort of files within the Android project, if they exist at all. I left a question in their github issue, hoping for a response.
I understand Xamarin is out of support since May, but my app's transition to .NET MAUI has not yet started. I'm grateful for any help on the matter.
